# BackupPC restore using command line tools

Tags: debian, backup

Can anyone suggest a proper command line tools and syntax that should be used to restore files created by BackupPC software?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you want to restore Foo's directory "bar" from his home directory (which is `/home/foo`), your command would look like this:

```
/usr/share/backuppc/bin/Backuppc_tarCreate -h host -n -1 -s /home/foo/bar > restore.tar
```

Flags :

```
-h host         Host from which the tar archive is created.

-n dumpNum      Dump number from which the tar archive is created. A negative number means relative to the end (eg -1 means the most recent dump, -2 2nd most recent etc).

-s shareName    Share name from which the tar archive is created.
```

Add a `-l` to the command to just list the matched filenames.

Answer (score 0):

It won't let me comment because I don't have enough rep, but a quick Google search gives this:

http://backuppc.sourceforge.net/faq/BackupPC.html#Compressed-file-format

Also this:

> You can use the BackupPC_zcat binary to decompress individual files 
>   manually.

http://www.backupcentral.com/phpBB2/two-way-mirrors-of-external-mailing-lists-3/backuppc-21/questions-about-compression-in-backuppc-93831/

Comment: I need to uncompress directory...